# Which XPath version is supported in PhantomJS?

Tags: selenium, xpath, phantomjs, version, ghostdriver

I'm using Selenium with PhantomJS. How can I find out which version of XPath is used in PhantomJS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly check whether specific functions are supported or not. For example, [`boolean()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-boolean) is provided by XPath 1.0, but [`abs()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-abs) is only provided by XPath 2.0.

**PhantomJS 1.x & 2.0 only supports XPath 1.0.**

Full script:

```js
var page = require('webpage').create();

console.log(JSON.stringify(page.evaluate(function(){
    var b = -1, body = -1, abs = -1;
    try{
        b = document.evaluate("boolean('a')", document, null, XPathResult.BOOLEAN_TYPE, null).booleanValue;
    }catch(e){}
    try{
        body = !!document.evaluate("//body", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
    }catch(e){}
    try{
        abs = document.evaluate("abs(-10.5)", document, null, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE, null).numberValue;
    }catch(e){}
    return {
        "boolean": b,
        "body": body,
        "abs(-10.5)": abs,
    };
}), undefined, 4));
phantom.exit();
```

Output:

```js
{
    "abs(-10.5)": -1,
    "body": true,
    "boolean": true
}
```